# How to loop back if password/username is wrong and print to user

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently writing in python to login to a website but want to facilitate as much user error as possible.

I want the code to print "Username/Password Incorrect" and then loop back to enter the username and password again.

Sadly I cant share the website with you as its on an intranet.

My Code:

```
#Enter Username
username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, value='j_username')
username.send_keys(input('Enter Username:'))

#Enter Password
password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, value='j_password')
password.send_keys(input('Enter Password:'))
```

I was wondering if its possible to get the error and loop back when this element is the displayed on the website:

[image]

Thanks for anyone who helps

Comment: Find the invalid password element by (class, xpath, id, etc), if it is there then output and wait for input. If not continue

Comment: don't `"loop back"` but normally run in `while True:`-loop and use `break` to exit this loop when you will use correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 possible scenarios: **Login success** and **Login fail**. You need to wait for the error message to appear in order to retry once it's here.

First let's import what we need

```
from selenium import webdriver as driver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

We can then start iterating

```
timeout = 5
error_msg_selector = '//div[@class="error"]' // example selector by class    

while True:
    try_login() // put your 4 lines in this function
    try:
        is_error_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'element_id'))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(is_error_present)
        print('Error message found, trying again')
        driver.refresh()
        continue
    except TimeoutException:
        print('Timed out while waiting for the error')
        break
print('We got out of the loop, login succeeded')
```

Note: It might be better to find an element that indicates successful login instead of the opposite, so that you don't have to check for multiple error messages.

Answer (score 0):

`.current_url` returns the url the driver is currently on. If you have a unique identifier in the successful login attempt you could run a while loop with a not statement in it and keep looping through until the user successfully loges in and the condition is met.